# Как сохранить локализацию пользователя в куках для последующих заходов на сайт?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookie, wordpress-плагины, wpml

Есть сайт на **wordpress** с установленным [плагином wpml](https://wpml.org/ru/) для 2ух языковых локализаций (потенциально может быть больше).

Хочу сделать так, чтобы в куках запоминало пользовательский язык на 30 дней (он его сам выбирает через переключалку `wpml`) и если пользователь заново заходит с любой страницы с новой ссылкой, то, чтобы его всегда перекидывало на ту локализацию, которая у него установлена в куках.
Русский стоит по умолчанию *(ru)*.

Прописываю в самом верху до тега `<!DOCTYPE html>` вот такую инструкцию (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` использую, чтобы определить пользователь воспользовался переключалкой или заново открыл страницу):

```
<?php 
$default_lang = apply_filters( 'wpml_default_language', null );
if($default_lang!= ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) {
    setcookie('language', ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, time() + 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && $_COOKIE['language']!= ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
        setcookie('language', ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE, time() + 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
    else {
      $wpml_permalink = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', get_the_permalink() , $_COOKIE['language'] );
      if(isset($wpml_permalink)) {
        wp_redirect( $wpml_permalink );
        exit;
      }
    }
} ?>
```

Работает хорошо при первом заходе *(ru)* и переключении на другую локализацию *(en)*, но, если переключателем возвращаюсь на исходную локализацию *(ru)*, то при новом заходе на сайт по старой ссылкой *(en)* пользователя снова кидает на *(en)* страницу, хотя он в предыдущем заходе воспользовался переключалкой на *(ru)*. [Надеюсь, доступно описал проблему]

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: у wpml [есть режим](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/automatic-redirect-based-on-browser-language/) - использовать язык, который указан в браузере

Comment: @Greg-- да, но это не всегда верно работает, особенно, если в браузере используется другой язык нежели на сайте. Плюс некоторые посты имеют только одну языковую версию и условия партнёрских программ на разных локализациях отличаются, поэтому хочу настроить кастомное решение, чтобы пользователь мог выбрал какую версию хочет использовать

Comment: У wpml есть свои куки: wp-wpml_current_language и wp-wpml_current_admin_language_(some-hash).

Comment: @KAGG Design допустим. Но, если я переключил на другую локализацию от исходной, то `wp-wpml_current_language` не запомнит это переключение при новом заходе - выберет default. Или вы имели ввиду перезапись этой куки при определенных условиях чтобы не создавать новую?

Comment: Может подойдет или на толкнет в нужную сторону [вот это](https://tombroucke.be/blog/wpml-remember-users-language-choice/) решение

Comment: @Greg да, работает! Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдено решение согласно [статье](https://tombroucke.be/blog/wpml-remember-users-language-choice/) которую скинул @Greg

**functions.php**

```
/**
 * Add ?switch_lang=lang to all url's in the languaqe switcher
 */
add_filter( 'icl_ls_languages', function( $languages ){
    global $sitepress;
    foreach( $languages as $lang_code => $language ){
        $languages[$lang_code]['url'] = add_query_arg( array( 'switch_language' => $lang_code ), $languages[$lang_code]['url'] );
    }
    return $languages; 
} );

/**
 * Update language cookie when user switches language
 */
add_action( 'init', function (){

    $switch_language = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'switch_language', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if( $switch_language ) {
        $languages = icl_get_languages();

        if( array_key_exists( $switch_language, $languages ) ) {
            setcookie('language', $switch_language, time() + 90 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);

            wp_redirect( strtok( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}, 1);

/**
 * Switch language if the user has selected his language before
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    // Disable for admin area & only for main query
    if( is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Disable for logged in users
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    $switch_language           = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'switch_language', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );
    $user_selected_language    = filter_input( INPUT_COOKIE, '_language', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if ( $user_selected_language && !$switch_language ) {
        do_action( 'wpml_switch_language', $user_selected_language );
    }
}, 1);
```